# Published vue component has no css (NPM)

Tags: css, vue.js, npm

This is the first time I am publishing a Vue component to NPM and everything works fine, except the fact that the CSS is not present. It all works as expected when I run it locally but if I create a test project, install the npm package and import the component there is no CSS.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new Vue project
- run `npm install elementable-vue`
- Use this template for App.vue: https://github.com/sandermaas/elementable-vue/blob/master/src/App.vue
- Change the import (in the template) to `import ElemenTable from 'elementable-vue'`
- run 'npm run serve'

You can check out the source code on https://github.com/sandermaas/elementable-vue

I can't figure out why this is not working so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your css as well in app.vue of your newly created project:

```
<style>
  @import '~elementable-vue/dist/elementable-vue.css';
</style>
```

Comment: is this always required to do? Is there a way to include CSS automatically with the component?

Comment: I may be wrong, but AFAIK it is required to import your css as well. I am not too sure if there is a way to automatically import or not.